# Spherical law of cosine what does the 'a' represent?

Tags: distance, spherical-geometry, excel

I want to use the spherical law of cosine formula,
 θ = atan2( sin Δλ ⋅ cos φ2 , cos φ1 ⋅ sin φ2 − sin φ1 ⋅ cos φ2 ⋅ cos Δλ ),  to calculate distances between coordinates, but, I cannot for the life of me remember what the 'a' stands for.

Can some please help me out?

Comment: `atan` is arctangent. The a is not a stand-alone multiplier, `atan` is all one word. [See this](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'atan' is short for arctangent, or inverse tangent. Here is the [Excel explanation of the ATAN2 function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/atan2-HP005208991.aspx) (since you used the Excel tag), and [a detailed look at ways to implement the calculation](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html).

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're referring to the 'a' in front of the 'tan'. It's not a variable, 'atan' is the arctangent or inverse tangent.

Another form for same, in mathematics, is this: tan<sup>-1</sup>

Comment: Okay awesome im just used to seeing Arctan not atan @wxmacman